# Simulated spatial data representation in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, igraph

I want to visualise the following simulated dataset:

[image: See image 1.]

```
time <- seq(1,10)
N.1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
N.2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
N.3 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
N.4 <- c(0,1,5,6,10,1,2,2,6,7)
N.5 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
N.6 <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
N.7 <- c(0,1,1,2,2,4,6,6,6,3)
result_snip <- data.frame(time,N.1,N.2,N.3,N.4,N.5,N.6, N.7)
```

The simulation tracks the number of infected individuals in one of the 7 populations over time. The populations are connected in a circular fashion.

[image: See image 2.]

(image created with the igraph package)

I wish to create a figure which roughly displays the number infected individuals in each population while also displaying the populations' connectivity. For example the size of the nodes or their colour could be proportional to the number of infected people. However, I am open to any suggestions, regarding the best way to visualise this dataset.

Thank you for considering this problem.

Comment: Can you draw a simple mockup of the kind of plot you want? Or are you looking for for help on choosing the kind of plot to best represent this data? If it's the latter, then [stats.se] might be a better place for this, since it's more of a stats/data visualization problem than a programming one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can try the code below

```
g <- make_ring(length(result_snip) - 1) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "name", value = names(result_snip)[-1])

g_layout <- layout_nicely(g)

apply(
  result_snip,
  1,
  function(v) {
    g %>%
      set_vertex_attr(name = "color", value = v[-1] != 0) %>%
      set_vertex_attr(name = "size", value = 10 + v[-1]) %>%
      plot(main = paste0(names(v[1]),"=", v[1]), layout = g_layout)
  }
)
```

which will generate a seris of plots and one of them looks like

[image]

Comment: Thanks Thomas, This is exactly what I was looking for! Ive had a play around with the code, and it can be adapted for my full simulation as well! However, when I tried creating an animation with it, the nodes of the ring keep changing positions randomly compared to the the previous point in time. I guess this is because we create a new ring for every timepoint and each time the nodes are placed randomly. Do you know if theres any way to fixate the ring somehow? thanks again, Dom

Comment: @not.a.hackerman You can try my updated answer, which specified the layout of graph before the `apply()`

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for!